# Error in rbind(meslek1, asd) : object 'asd' not found in r

Tags: r, diff, rbind

I write this code in R to produce a csv file from my diff function, but I'm getting that error.

```r
for(girdi1 in 1:304) {
    print(girdi1)
    meslek1<-diff(as.data.frame(amges[,girdi1])[,1], lag=1, differences=1)
    asd <- rbind(meslek1,asd)
}
write.csv(asd, file='asd.csv')
```

Comment: `asd` doesn't exist. You have to create it first as empty object.

Comment: thank u this solve the problem but this time it writed each query over the list. I want to write each query under previous one.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: You should add the tag `r` to you question, since your question is for this language.

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `asd`-object doesn't exist you have to create it first as empty object outside of the loop.
2. To change the order of the rows while binding, change the order within `rbind()`

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,3,4)

> rbind(a,b)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    2    3
b    2    3    4

> rbind(b,a)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
b    2    3    4
a    1    2    3
```

That is then:

```
asd <- vector()

for(girdi1 in 1:304) {
    print(girdi1)
    meslek1<-diff(as.data.frame(amges[,girdi1])[,1], lag=1, differences=1)
    asd <- rbind(asd, meslek1)
}
write.csv(asd, file='asd.csv')
```